# When I open the nvim init.vim file, this error comes for Neoclide coc.vim

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim, pyx

I get this error when I try to open the init.vim file for neovim, for neoclide coc.vim. Any solutions? in WSL(Ubuntu)

```
[coc.nvim] Error on execute :pyx command, ultisnips feature of coc-snippets requires pyx support on vim. use :CocOpenLog for details
```

Comment: I tryed https://stackoverflow.com/a/73285807/4353286 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71449209/4353286, that resolves my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Enter command `pip install pynvim` in your command line. It helped me. And before this you should have python on your PC.

Answer (score 4):

you choose correct version of python in init.vim

> let g:python3_host_prog="/usr/bin/version python"
> example

> let g:python3_host_prog="/usr/bin/python3.10"

Answer (score 1):

I tried with installing pynvim and also have the latest pip (21.3.1). My vim version is 9.0 and compiled it from scratch.
But while searching the features included with vim, I realised that I had not included python. After following [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17502) answer, I enabled python while compiling vim. My issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had to [upgrade `pip` first](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#upgrading-pip), then run `pip install pynvim`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you default python install broke for some reason on you machine (was the same for me).
Try running the `python` command from the terminal.
If you get command not recognized than you know this is the problem.

Reinstalling python or
set the python the python path that vim uses to an installed python version that works

```
let g:python3_host_prog="/usr/bin/version python"
```

Assuming you have python3 installed.